# Displaying null value on jsp page

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, servlets

I am a beginner to servlets and jsp.
I am currently struck with one jsp problem that when page is running on server the statements in scriptlet tag are getting null values as when page is loading the statement is executed but when button is clicked no action is performed and I am getting null values.

Script

```
function showTable() {
            var ele = document.getElementById("first");
            if(ele.style.display == "none") {

                ele.style.display = "block";   
            }
```

Code

```
<form action="" method="post">  
<table>
        <tr>
            <td>From</td>
            <td><input type="date" name="fromDate" id="datepicker"/></td>

            <td>To</td>
            <td><input type="date" name="toDate" id="datepicker1"/></td>


        </tr>
</table>
<input type="button" value="Search" onclick="return showTable();"/>     
</form>


<div id="first" style="display:none;">
<div class="one">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Check No</td>
        <td>Check Date</td>
        <td>Check Amount</td>
    </tr>
```

=str_to_date('"+FromDate+"','%d/%m/%Y') and CHECKDATE

```
        <tr>
            <td> <%=checkno %> </a></td>
            <td><%=date %> </td>
            <td><%=amount %> </td>  

        </tr>

        <%} %>
        <%

    } catch (Exception e) {
        out.println("wrong entry" + e);
    }
%> 
    </table>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
</div>

</form>
```

Error:
fromDatenull toDatenull
Loading class `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'.
Connection successful!!!

query SELECT * FROM Sppayment WHERE CHECKDATE>=str_to_date('null','%d/%m/%Y') and CHECKDATE<=str_to_date('null','%d/%m/%Y')

Comment: You can using alert function to check values of fromDate and toDate, they should not be null. Also check the case 'FromDate' -> 'fromDate"

Answer (score 0):

Using strict comparison operator === would help here.

```
function showTable() {
    var ele = document.getElementById("first");
    **if(ele.style.display === "none") { // please see the strict comparison here**
                ele.style.display = "block";   
}
```

If the issue is about getting null values, then please add alert or log the value to console.